# What is the difference between <Route component={MyComponent} /> and <Route>{MyComponent}<Route />?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have seen 2 ways to define routes in React:
`<Route path="/" component={MyComponent} />`
and 
`<Route path="/">{MyComponent}<Route />`
Can anyone explain me the difference between the two?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake...the second way I meant is ```<Route path="/"><MyComponent /><Route />``` and not ```<Route path="/">{MyComponent}<Route />```

Answer (score 0):

You should not really use the:

```
<Route path="/">{MyComponent}<Route />
```

variant. It will only work if the component is a Function component(if you try to put a class component you will get an error), and only if the component doesn't have hooks inside. Route type definition states that in props.children it recieves a render function that returns a React.ReactNode based on route props (history, match parameters, ...) or directly a React.ReactNode. So you should really use it like this:

```
<Route path="/"><MyComponent /><Route />
```

Or if your component need route props (and this is then the same as ):

```
<Route path="/">{(props) => <MyComponent {...props} />}<Route />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: So difference is that in the second case (<Route path="/"><MyComponent /><Route />), MyComponent wont get any of the route props(match parameters, history object, ...). In both cases the component is rendered when path matches.

With the new hooks that react router now ships with you can access those values (see more: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Hooks).

For more information about different rendering methods see: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Route/route-render-methods . There you can also see what props you get when a route is matched.